# Guide for Securing Web Services with WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere, digital-signature, x509

I'm a WS-Security newbie who has been tasked with applying WS-Security to our existing SOAP Web Services. Our application runs on WebSphere Application Server 8.5, and we're using Full Profile (not Liberty).

Features that I'm to incorporate include:

- Adding Message ID, Service Request, Timestamps, (optional) SAML assertions, (optional) Sequence Numbers to SOAP messages
- Digital signatures on SOAP messages using X.509 certificates
- Authentication using X.509 certificates

I have browsed the *WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Administration and Configuration Guide for the Full Profile* IBM Redbook(http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248056.html), and I've gone through some tutorials and samples in the *IBM WebSphere Application Server V7.0 Web Services Guide* IBM Redbook (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247758.html), but I still feel like I'm in over my head with how to configure WAS to support these features.

Does anyone have recommended references -- books, code samples, YouTube videos, etc. -- for how I might come up to speed fairly quickly on at least some of these topics?

Comment: IBM developerWorks would have [what you're looking for](https://www.ibm.com/Search/?q=web+services+security&lnk=mhsrch&v=18&en=utf&lang=en&cc=us&sn=dw&dws=dw&hpp=20). As a side note, questions asking for external resources tend to be frowned upon on StackOverflow - They don't contribute much to SO itself. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The WebSphere WS-Security component has a set of pages outside of the Knowledge Center that provides some condensed information.  Here is a link to the FAQ:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972065

It has some Q&A about the component.

On that page there is a tab to get to a page that gives a little run-down on the theory of asymmetric XML digital signature: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972066 . For your purposes, you probably should ready only up until 'Signature calculation trace snip'.  If you want to read more about certificates, you can skip down to 'Certificate Paths (CertPaths)'.  Most of the value between those two sections is for when you are trying to make your configuration match a provider and all you have to work with is a message that 'works'.

There is another tab on the page called Examples: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972078 .  That page has links into the WebSphere Application Server Knowledge Center for all the JAX-WS WS-Security policy/binding configuration tasks and API usage scenarios.  You can read through the descriptions and find a task/scenario that is closest that what you want to do.  The first six in the first set of tasks are listed in the order of complexity (thinking required, not the number of steps required).

Good luck in your pursuit!

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere full profile, you can enable ws-security by attaching policyset set. Policyset can be attached to service or operation. 
Although you can create policyset by admin tool, you could simply attach default policyset shipped with WebSphere. For example, if you want to use X509, you can attach "Username WSSecurity default", or you can clone the policyset, and edit it to meet your requirement.
Here are links for using different token types.
1. SAML:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_configsamlbearertoken.html
2. X509:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_general_policyset.html